# File handling exceptions - handling open file and file not found

Tags: c#, .net, file, exception

In a .NET console application, a file is being opened for reading, inside a try/catch block. The user should be alerted with a message printed to the console, if the file is open, or if it doesn't exist. The messages should be separated for each case. How can this be achieved? Using `System.IOException` doesn't differentiate between these two cases, if it is like the following:

```
try
{
    // open the file
}
catch (System.IOException)
{
    // print a message (Console.WriteLine)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to the Try-Catch approach, you could use [`FileNotFoundException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filenotfoundexception?view=netframework-4.8) to check if the exception was raised as specified file/path could not be found

```
try
{
  // Attempt Opening the file
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
  // File Not Found
}
catch(IOException e) when (e.Message.Contains($"The process cannot access the file '{filePath}' because it is being used by another process"))
{
  // File being used by another process
}
catch(IOException e) 
{
  // An I/O error occurred while opening the file (could be any other reason)
}
```

Futhermore, you could filter the IOException to ensure the particular error is due to the fact the file is being used by any other process.

Alternatively, you could also use [`File.Exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=netframework-4.8) to check if the File Exists before attempting to open the file.

```
if(File.Exists(filePath))
{
   try
   {
     // File Exist, open the file
   }
   catch(IOException e)
   {
     // Error opening the file
   }
}
else
{
  // File do not exist
}
```